# Change Hidden Field Value Based on Dropdown Choice

Tags: javascript

I need some basic javascript help. I have a form with a dropdown selection. Based on the choice in that dropdown selection, I want to change the value of a hidden field.

For example, if the user chooses "Google" on the dropdown, I want the hidden field to display "https://google.com" and if the user chooses "Bing" I want the hidden field to display "https://bing.com."

One caveat (not sure if this changes the script) is that I am setting unique values for the dropdown choices. For example, "Google" has a value of 5 and Bing has a value of 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried the simple script below but I am very unexperienced with Javascript so it is likely not correct.

```
<script>
var service = $('#service').val();
if(service == 'Google'){
   $('#hidden_field').val('https://google.com/')
} else {
   $('#hidden_field').val('https://bing.com')
}  
</script>
```

In the example above, I'd like the service choice of Google to add the Google URL to the hidden field, and all other choices will display Bing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your javascript code into a function and bind it to an event handler:

```
<script>
    function fill()
    {
      let service = $('#service').val();
      if(service == 'Google'){
       $('#hidden_field').val('https://google.com/')
      } else {
       $('#hidden_field').val('https://bing.com')
      }
    }

    /* And the binding */
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $('#service').on("change", fill);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#service').on("change", fill);` instead of `$('#service').on("change", fill());`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to respond to the change event of the select list:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#service').on('change', function(e) {
        var score=e.target.value;
        $('#hidden_field').val(score);
    });
})
</script>
```